# GB2312 encoding hex string how to parse to QString

Tags: qt

I have a QString and convert it to hex string with GB2312:

```
QString temp = "我".toLocal8Bit().toHex().toUpper();
```

and then I get `temp = "CED2".`

Now I want convert "CED2" to "我".

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Qt class `QTextCodec` for character conversion.

`QTextCodec::fromUnicode` and `QTextCodec::toUnicode`.

Saving that data as hex string is no good idea at all, I would prefer an QByteArray. But anyway here it is:

```
QString MyOrgStr(QByteArray::fromHex(QByteArray("CED2")));
```

I'm not sure what locale your source code document is saved in. The way you call this method it must be in GB2312 otherwise it wont work like expected.

I would suggest using `QTextCodec` like so:

```
QTextCodec* c = QTextCodec::codecForName("GB18030");
if (c) {
    QString s = c->toUnicode("我");
    delete c;
} else {
    // Error, codec not installed
}
```

Concerning Qt documentation, the codec `GB18030` should be used here.

> The GBK codec provides conversion to and from the Chinese
>   GB18030/GBK/GB2312 encoding. GBK, formally the Chinese Internal Code
>   Specification, is a commonly used extension of GB 2312-80. Microsoft
>   Windows uses it under the name codepage 936.

Comment: Thank you at all.Because in my project,user can input char use hex,and tell me the encode.so I need to be able to convert hex strings to normal string.`QString temp = QString::fromLocal8Bit(QByteArray::fromHex(textEditSingleLineInput->toPlainText().toLocal8Bit()).data());`